# Ho to fix Material UI upgrade error on nextjs application - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ..in _document.js

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I upgraded Material UI from V4 to V5 in my nextJS application. Replaced styles and followed the migration guide but it gives me error on load "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports." in _document.js

My Package.json has this

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.115",
"@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
"@mui/styles": "^5.11.2",
"mdi-material-ui": "^7.6.0",
```

Stacktrace

```
index.js?46cb:594 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4053:17)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3690:29)
    at Object.renderToString (/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:4298:27)
    at renderPage (/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:680:46)
    at ctx.renderPage (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_document.js:360:26)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:350:67)
    at Document.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:43:16)
    at MyDocument.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_document.js:368:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/utils.js:75:33)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

UPDATE: I found out my issue is with the StylesProvider. Yet to figure out how to fix it

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

import { StylesProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material'


    <ConditionalWrapper
                        condition={jss}
                        wrapper={children => <StylesProvider jss={jss}>{children}</StylesProvider>}>
                        <ConditionalWrapper
                            condition={theme}
                            wrapper={children => <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
                            </StyledEngineProvider>}>             
                                  {children}
                        </ConditionalWrapper>
                    </ConditionalWrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized StyledEngineProvider allows you to customize the current instance of StylesProvider used by MUI and so we dont need both